# Are this user's title edits incorrect?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit, specific-user

I've come across [this user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11198719/colby?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) suggested edits in the queue a fair few times, all changing capitalization on the title like this:

[image]

If I'm understanding this right, the suggested text after the edit would be "Problems using SerialPort to communicate between Node.js and Arduinoproblems using SerialPort to communicate between Node.js and Arduino" (the fixed title is prepended instead of replacing the orignal).

Am I interpreting the suggestion right, or is the suggestion actually being done correctly? And if not, is there something I should do about it besides just rejecting the suggestions?

Comment: Closer, this is not about whether or not the minor edit should be approved, I know that is ok. It's an issue about whether or not the suggestion was done correctly (it wasn't in this case) and how I should handle it besides rejecting. See answer below.

Comment: The duplicate I selected already list reject as the right action and suggest flagging for mod attention in case of repeated actions. There is nothing particularly new in my answer. (you may also learn how to find who closed post by searching related info on meta... )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But that's not all it's asking, it's asking if their interpretation of the inline edit format is correct (which it is).

Comment: asportnoy if you also have question on how that diff rendered feel free to ask separate question. As @NickstandswithUkraine points out this question could be interpreted as asking about that too. Based on the fact you've accepted my answer you mainly interested in user's behavior rather than rendering.

Comment: Was mainly looking for confirmation on that part right, which your answer already addressed. I do still think that this should be reopened though since it is different from the question you linked.

Comment: @asportnoy than you should un-accept my answer (which is almost exact duplicate of the answer I linked) and edit out the part about "what to do" (which is the part addressed by my answer and duplicate).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the "what to do" was still a part of my question. Your answer addressed both parts, so I see no reason to un-accept it.

Comment: Ask 1 specific question per post. You can click on tabs to see the before & after versions side by side, formatted or markdown.

Comment: It looks like yet another scheme to earn reputation points with the ***least amount of work*** possible: Double the title (and make it ***look*** like the capitalisation issue has been fixed). It only requires a copy and a paste (and some selection actions). And it circumvents the six-character limit (it doesn't apply to titles).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Why is that less work than just changing the capitalization without duplicating anything?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Seems like effectively `capitaliseFirstWord(title) + restofTitleWithoutFirstWord(title) + restofTitleWithoutFirstWord(title)` which is very consistent. Supposedly it's automated and there is a simple bug in the code.

Comment: When I see *Problem with...* and it's ilk I find myself wanting a lot more information about what the problem is. I mean, DUH! Obviously there's a problem or the question wouldn't be asked. Title needs more work than simply capitalization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, reject (or even "Reject and Edit") is an appropriate action for changes that limit edit to just couple of letters and ignoring the rest of the posts or even reading the title to the end like:

> **J**avascript not applying to my sql ids help plz

If multiple edits show the same pattern consider flagging for moderator attention so they can send a message to the user reminding about proper edits. If you are adventurous enough you can comment yourself on one of the posts the user edited (they should be notified as long as they show up in the history even if autocomplete will not show their name after @).

Comment: I don't see a "flag" button within the queue. Is there somewhere else I have to go to do that?

Comment: @asportnoy you can always open post in separate window and flag there. Or if you already looking at OP profile flag any of their posts or comments with detailed explanation.

Comment: (I'll delete this answer shortly as we already have nearly identical one I selected as duplicate)

Comment: So to confirm, just the regular "flag" button for the post, right? And I assume I'd use "In need of moderator intervention"?

Comment: @asportnoy Yes, "In need of moderator intervention", make sure to provide enough details, ideally with link(s) to problematic edits.